# Deep Linking iOS Push Notifications with React native

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, native, deep-linking

How to use Deep-Linking in Push Notification. Can u send me syntax & Example for iOS React native.

Comment: Can you add what you currently have implemented for realising the deep linking?

Comment: i just follow this tutorial https://www.lullabot.com/articles/navigation-and-deep-linking-with-react-native

Comment: I am using PushNotificationIOS it is working fine. I have multiple tabs and views in my app. My question is that what is best place to add PushNotificationIOS code in the app. And also how to send device token to server ? On notification received (have to open specific app view and then able to provide option to go back to the main view in the app ) Could anyone can help me in this case?